# If $b^2\mid a^2$, then prove $b\mid a^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $b^2\mid a^2$, then prove $b\mid a^2$.

To prove, need consider the fact that if $a$ is odd, then $a^2$ too is. Let, for a suitable integer $k$, $a=2k+1$, then $a^2= 4k^2+4k+1$.
So, if $b^2\mid a^2,$ then both ($a,b$) have the same parity.

There are two cases, based on the parity of $a,b$ being odd or even. 
(i) If both odd: let for suitable integers $k,m$, $a=2k+1, b=2m+1$; $a^2= 4k^2 + 4k+1, b^2=4m^2+4m+1$. 

=> $(4m^2 + 4m+1)\mid (4k^2 + 4k+1)$

 Unable to show algebraic proof further for the next step.

(ii) if both even: it is obvious that if $b^2$ divides $a^2$, then $b\mid a^2$. but cannot show the algebraic proof.

Comment: $a^2=b^2\times n\implies a^2=b\times (bn)$.

Comment: Did you mean to try to prove that $b\,|\,a$?

Comment: That's all. Okay, fine but please help me do an algebraic proof too. No, only $b\mid a^2$. But, iIf can show $b\mid a$ based on the premise, then please do show. It was part of the proof to show irrationality of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: My proof is algebraic.  The stronger claim follows immediately from unique factorization.

Comment: @lulu Please show the stronger proof. Also, is there some issue with my approach that am not leading anywhere (even for both $a,b$ as even numbers).

Comment: If $b$ does not divide $a$ then there is a prime $p$ for which $v_p(b)>v_p(a)$ but in that case $v_p(b^2)>v_p(a^2)$ so $b^2$ does not divide $a^2$.  I don't understand your argument at all...it appears to just focus on the parity of $a,b$ but why?

Comment: @jtender Is this some kind of spoof? If 100 divides n, you are unsure if 10 divides n?

Comment: @lulu You rightly said, as my focus is on the possibility of divisibility from the odd, even angle. I even now am not clear why that is a wrong thing to do, and am now thinking it as a complementary condition to check. I mean that am not completely clear about the prime factorization being able to do everything, with out need to check the possibility. so, I try to understand by example: $3^2 \mid 18^2$, here parity is not important at all. Thanks for correcting my way of approaching the divisibility problem. Hence, I can conclude that my (above) way of reasoning will 'never' work.

Comment: @almagest I also was confused, and hope that you are erring on the part that it is not $100\mid n \implies 10\mid n$; but it is $100 \mid n^2 \implies 10\mid n^2$. the difference is both $100, n^2$ are squares of some integer.

Comment: @lulu I was hopeful that you were to show based on $b^2 \mid a^2$, that $b\mid a$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, as to the parity of $a,b$. My argument shows that $b^2\,|\,a^2\implies b\,|\,a$ as desired (I worked from the contrapositive).

Comment: @lulu Your first comment was however proof for $b \mid a^2$. Based on one comment (by almagest) above, how to prove that: if $b^2\mid a$ is given, then $b\mid a$ cannot be proved. Sorry, it is crap, as your first comment applies also to prove that : if $b^2\mid a \implies b\mid a$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  As presented, your post is nonsense.  This is my final comment.

Comment: @jjtender. So you are saying that if something is true for *all* integers $n$ then it is not necessarily true for squares? Wake up.

Comment: @almagest Thanks for your nice wake-up comment. I hope you mentioned that in reference to the comment to lulu, regarding the crap question : to prove that if $b^2 \mid a$ is given, then $b\mid a$ cannot be proved. Yes, that was a mistake, & not only that but a blunder! Else, please tell, if you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b^2\mid a^2 \implies a^2=kb^2\implies a=b\sqrt k$. Since $a$ is an integer, we can say that $k$ is perfect square. So $k=c^2\implies a^2=c^2b^2\implies a=cb$. Hence, 
$$b\mid a\implies b\mid a^2$$

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma**
If $k\mid m$ and $m\mid n$, then $k\mid n$.

**Proof**
Indeed, since $k\mid m$, $m=kj$ for some integer $j$. Likewise $n=ml$ for some integer $l$ whence $n=k(jl)$ as desired.

For your problem observe that $b\mid b^2$ and $b^2\mid a^2$, so...

Comment: Can you please extend my algebraic reasoning too, or my way would not work for some reason.

Comment: @jtender The main problem with the reasoning in the question is that it is long-winded (which deters most people from bothering to read it carefully). The secondary problem is that it is misconceived. There is no good reason to treat the cases of $a$ odd and $a$ even separately.